# Getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION instead of failure

Tags: ios, unit-testing

As you can see in the image below when I run my tests I'm not getting the failures results. I get `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` instead. Why?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert()` is a C function for checking necessary conditions of program and not of a test. It's normal behaviour is to print a message and to abort the program with a signal, if the condition is not fulfilled. You should use `XCTAssertTrue()` or `XCTAssertEquals()` instead.